# Piece of fabric in planter, how to use it?

Tags: containers

I bought few planters with soil and basil seeds included. There was also piece of fabric at the bottom that I do not know what to do with. There were no instructions and I wasn't able to google anything (I do not know right keywords I guess, I am very new to anything gardening related).

planter looks like this: 
[image: top]
[image: bottom]
[image: together]

An idea occurred to me while writing this question, was I supposed to thread that piece of fabric through those slits at the bottom of top part so that it could pull moisture from bottom part up toward the soil? If so, how exactly is it supposed to look? Is it too late to fix it now?

Bonus questions:
What is this type of planter called and how to use (water) it properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guess is correct. It is a self-watering planter. The cloth (wick) is intended to be threaded through a hole in the bottom of the pot where it drops down into standing water in the drip tray. Example from wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-irrigated_planter

That said, most people who are well acquainted with container gardening would not use a self watering device such as this. Although it would work as designed, you run a high possibility of water-logging the soil and negatively impacting the health of your plants. You are better off just watering the plant as needed. Having standing water under your plants is not a good idea.

The only time I have used self-watering devices is occasions when I am away for long periods and there is no one who can water for me.